# Having issues with Django dbshell

Tags: django

Please i dont know what is wrong, i used south for model migration, my question is, is it
perfectly alright to use south or is the django traditional way i.e (`manage.py dbshell`) any better.

My second question, i tried using `manage.py dbshell`, but i get the message each time.

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3` is a database that saves the records in a single file, the command `dbshell` is for going into the database shell. It works with MySQL and PostgreSQL, but not with SQLite.

BTW, if you are using *south*, its fine, `dbshell` is when you need to do something with the database but, if *south* does it for you, is fine.

Comment: no problem, if you like the answer, mark it as correct and give me some of street creed :)

Answer (score 7):

There's is dbshell support for sqlite actually, you just need to install command line utility (package named `sqlite3` in Ubuntu).

Comment: Go to http://www.sqlite.org/download.html , download "sqlite-shell-win32-…", unzip it and place into some folder in your PATH (e.g. C:\Windows).

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to update the `PATH` environment variable with the installed folder for sqlite, where the executable sqlite3.exe resides